# CodeNameOne - React on Tree expansion or collapse

Tags: java, treeview, codenameone

I'm using a subclass of the Tree class in my project. I'm having two problems. First I would like to change the text of the not-leaf nodes when they expand or collapse. Second when expanding some nodes the tree exceeds the screen and even if scrollable is set to true, I can not scroll all the way to the bottom. To be specific the tree always shows as many nodes as in the beginning. If it begins with 10 nodes, then after expanding I will only be able to scroll the ten top nodes and not the whole tree.

While trying to figure out both points I looked for a callback on expansion/collapse, but it seems to be private. Is there any way to add a listener on expansion/collapse or other way to solve my issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree should be placed in a non-scrollable hierarchy where it can take responsibility over the scrolling e.g. in the center of a border layout on the `Form`.

You can override the [createNode](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/tree/Tree.html#createNode-java.lang.Object-int-) method of `Tree` and build any type of `Component` you want. It can change it's text when it's expanded based on the events and do anything you want.